# GCC on Linux searching for a forward declared method in the wrong namespace

Tags: c++11, gcc, linker, forward-declaration

Consider the following scenario:

Source.cpp

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; } // function in global scope
```

Header.h

```
namespace ns
{
    class A
    {
    public:
        void do()
        {
            ...
            ...
            method();
            ...
            ...
        }
    private:
        int method()
        {
            ...
            ...
            int add(int a, int b); // forward declaration
            auto result = add(5, 10); // function call
            ...
            ...
            // do something with result
        }
    };
}
```

On *Windows (MS Compiler)*, the above works as expected.

On *Linux (GCC)*, it results in a linker error wherein the method `add()` is being reported as an *undefined reference*.

What's more, the error states that the compiler is trying to look for `add()` under the `ns` namespace, but it is clearly defined in the global namespace.

Does GCC on Linux behave differently than the MS compiler on Windows when linking methods that are forward declared? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

The MS compiler's name-lookup is non-conforming per C++11 Standard in resolving the
declaration of `int add(int a, int b)` within the body of `ns::A::method` to
a global declaration of the function defined in `Source.cpp`. That declaration is within namespace
`ns` and the function it *should* declare is `int ns::add(int a, int b)`, which as
GCC (or clang) complains, is not defined.

**C++11 § 3.5 para 7:**

> When a block scope declaration of an entity with linkage is not found to refer to some other declaration,
>   then that entity is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. However such a declaration does not
>   introduce the member name in its namespace scope. [ Example:

```
namespace X {
    void p() {
        q(); // error: q not yet declared
        extern void q(); // q is a member of namespace X
    }
    ...
    ...

    void q() { /* ... */ } // definition of X::q
}

void q() { /* ... */ } // some other, unrelated q
```

> end example ]

You have two alternatives:-

- Hoist the forward declaration of `int add(int a, int b)` out of namespace
  `ns` into the global namespace - the one where it is defined in `source.cpp`
- Enclose the definition of `int add(int a, int b)` in namespace `ns`:

**Source.cpp**

```
namespace ns {
    int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
}
```

Comment: So MS is having wrong implementation. Do you know if a bug has already been raised with them?